# Capybara Rspec has content twice

Tags: rspec, capybara

I'm a novice hobbyist, trying to write my first rspec ever for a 2017 rails project that use capybara 2.10.1 and rspec.

I got launchy, did save_and_open_page, ctrl-shift-c, right-clicked a link to find the xpath for some deep random bootstrap navbar log-in link:

```
scenario "valid with correct credentials", focus: true do
    expect(page).to have_link "LOG IN"
    find('#myNavbar > ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.signlogin > li:nth-child(2) > a').click
    expect(page).to have_content("Sign in").twice
    fill_in "Email", with: @fan.email
    fill_in "Password", with: @fan.password
    click_button "Sign in"

    find('.dropdown-toggle').click
    expect(page).to have_link "Logout"
    expect(page).to have_current_path root_path
  end
```

but, assuming because it's capybara 2.10.1, have_content("").twice gives me

```
Capybara::Ambiguous:
       Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching xpath "/html"
```

although i tried updating capybara but with the same result.

I could find something else unique to expect on the page, but have been unsuccessfully trying to solve it with google (a capybara apparently is twice the size of a beaver and is the largest rodent in the world).

any way to solve this?

Comment: "a capybara apparently is twice the size of a beaver and is the largest rodent in the world" - LOL :) Have an upvote.

Comment: thanks. .. well, i guess i have to wait until tomorrow to accept my own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.twice` support was released in Capybara [3.19.0](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/History.md#version-3190) version.

With older version of capybara 2.10.1, you can use following.

```rb
expect(page).to have_content("Sign in", count: 2)
```

Comment: I updated to 3.6.0 so I could use .twice but got the same result.  I've also tried ("Sign in", count: 2) with the same result, ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching xpath "/html", so perhaps it's something else.

Comment: ended up going expect(page).to have_button("Sign in").  ... now reading the docs